# Internal Database - ASP.NET Auto Web Site Registration on User Creation

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, web

I have built an internal Database for Clients. Its C# with an MS-SQL DB. I have integrated the ASP Website SQL Server and the Internal SQL Server to use the one database. Both the Website and the Internal Database are working.

I want to be able to automatically register a client to use the webpage once they have become a Client in my Internal Database. Using ASP (I am learning still) I see there is a membership provider and it seems to do all the validation and so on. Passwords are all handled and encrypted etc..

What would be the best way to add a user to the SQL Tables but keep the security and so on? Can I create a membership provider in my DB Client when adding a Client and use that to create the Clients Login to the Web Page?

I am using the default ASP .NET Web Application Template in VS 2010. The ASP Site is all standard config from the template.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the methods on the membership provider. Don't get into the specifics of how the membership provider is working, the whole point of the provider model is that you can swap out the default SQL one for any other implementation.

If you look at the `MembershipProvider` base class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) you can see the list of methods that it provides. You will need to call `Membership.CreateUser()` as part of your custom registration process, it has several overloads to choose between.

Comment: Yes I agree, using Chris Pels as an example, I can call Membership.CreateUser and it calls the Stored Proceedure to create the User in the database. I am thinking of creating a SQL link table and set the ID's to match my Clients in the Internal Database. For example my table might look like: [Client ID] [UserID] and then I can have the information on my website displayed for the correct login.

Comment: Can you tell me, whats the default password encryption format in the default Membership Provider? I see salt in there but is there more than one? Thanks!

Comment: If you look in Chris Pels' initialiser methods (near the top), you can see a line that checks the config for a value, and uses the Hashed format if it can't retrieve a value from config. All the default values get set in there, as well as some other stuff. Pretty ugly though! Right down at the bottom is the EncodePassword method which is where it actually happens if you want to know how the encryption works.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the default SQL Config and stored proceedures, we can use these.

See [this](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider).

The sample code by Chris Pels is excellent for helping with this solution. Thanks Chris!